# How to leverage the clumsy pushd and popd with the awsome dirs built-in command of Bash

Tags: bash, stack, directory-structure, built-in

Isn't there a more intuitive way of dealing with the directory stack than what is possible with `pushd` and `popd`?

I find the CLIs of the `pushd` and `popd` built-in commands presented to the user kind of mind-boggling. But at the same time I would love to make frequent use of the directory stack presented by the `dirs` built-in command.

So it took me quite a long time to figure out use cases and then to memorize the following ones:

1. `pushd` - toggle the two directories from the top.
2. `pushd +1` - change to the second from top directory.
3. `pushd -0` - change to the bottom from top directory.
4. `popd +0` - pop the top changing to the second from top directory.
5. `pushd -0; popd +1` - change to the bottom from top directory and pop the former top.

Still having to type them each time just to juggle with the directory stack feels way to heavy to me. I even can't come up with mnemonic names to alias those five use cases.

Any insights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recently I discovered the power of GNUs readline library and the short cuts in terms of key strokes it can provide to the user on Bash's command line.

I therefore defined the following hot keys in my `~/.inputrc` file. GNU readline's configuration file:

```
# "pushd" use case.
"\C-^": "\C-a\C-kpushd\C-m"

# "pushd +1" use case.
"\e<": "\C-a\C-kpushd +1\C-m"

# "popd +0" use case.
"\ex\e<": "\C-a\C-kpopd +0\C-m"

# "pushd -0" use case.
"\e>": "\C-a\C-kpushd -0\C-m"

# "pushd -0; popd +1" use case.
"\ex\e>": "\C-a\C-kpushd -0; popd +1\C-m"
```

I associate the hot keys from above as follows:

1. `<ctrl>-^` - `vim` hot key to toggle the current with the previous buffer.
2. `<alt>-<` - Shift left and carry.
3. `<alt>-x<` - Shift left and crop.
4. `<alt>->` - shift right and carry.
5. `<alt>-x>` - shift right and crop.

The `<ctrl>-ak` key strokes position the cursor at the beginning of the line (a) and delete (k) it. This is important because when `<ctrl-m>` (enter) is hit chances are that the user hit the hot key while in the middle of a sentence. The hot key value would get garbled with the current user input and bash couldn't execute it.

Answer (score 1):

For my own personal use, I have several directories that I *commonly* use, and would like to be able to switch between using `pushd`.  I came up with the following function for my `.bashrc`:

```
p() {
  pushd +"$(($(dirs -p | sed -n '1d;s,.*/,,;/^'"$1"'/{=;q;}')-1))" >/dev/null
}
```

Let's say I have a directory stack like so:

```
$ dirs -v
 0  ~/repos/local_only/configs
 1  ~/repos/virtualization
 2  ~/repos/local_only/work
 3  ~/repos/core
 4  ~/repos/local_only/my_test_repo
```

I can switch from the current directory to any other using just `p <letter>`, where `<letter>` is the start of the name of the directory.  (It can be more than one letter, of course.)  For instance, `p m` will switch to `my_test_repo`; `p w` will switch to `work`.

If I use `p c` from my `work` dir, it will switch to the next directory in the stack which starts with `c`, which in this case would be `core`.  (The `q` part of the `sed` command prevents it from returning more than the first result.)  To specifically switch to the `configs` dir instead, I could use `p con`, or just `p c` and then `p c` again.

The `1d` in the `sed` command is so that I don't ever switch to the current directory.  Thus I can switch between my `configs` dir and my `core` dir using just `p c`.

The redirection of `stdout` to `/dev/null` prevents the annoying (to me) execution of `dirs` after every execution of `pushd`.  (I have the current directory listed in my prompt anyway.)  However I don't silence `stderr`—so if I run `p q`, for example, I'll see:

```
$ p q
-bash: pushd: +-1: directory stack index out of range
```

---

**Complementary with builtins**

This doesn't replace `pushd` and `popd`; it's intended for fast switching.  To add to the directory stack I still use `pushd <directory_name>`.  And if I'm done in a specific directory (say, `virtualization`) I can just `p v` and then `popd`.

---

**Unlikely Errors:**

This probably won't work right with directory names that contain newlines, but that doesn't matter for my purposes.  In any case the worst it could do is `pushd` you to the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my workflow :

**0. CONF (FAKE DATA)**

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir -p foo/bar baz qux
```

**1. CONF**

```sh
dirs -v
cd foo/bar; pushd .; cd ../..
cd baz; pushd .; cd ..
cd qux; pushd .; cd ..
```

**2. RUN**

```sh
dirs -v
cd $(dirs +1) # switch to dir 1
cd $(dirs +2) # switch to dir 2
cd $(dirs +3) # switch to dir 3
```

May be better explained with a quick recording of this there: https://asciinema.org/a/148441

**PRO**

- at conf: minimal set of primitive and shortcut
- at run: idem. only use indexes. mostly readonly, they even never changes.